# how to new a java class as int[] type

Tags: java

How to convert `int[]` to the class `Cell`?

```
public List<int[]> getThem(List<int[]> theList) {
    List<int[]> list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (int[] x : theList)
        if (x[0] == 4)
            list1.add(x);
    return list1;
}
```

I want to refactor as following :

```
public List<Cell> getFlaggedCells() {
    List<Cell> flaggedCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    for (Cell cell : gameBoard)
        if (cell.isFlagged())
            flaggedCells.add(cell);
    return flaggedCells;
}
```

How can I make a class `Cell`  as `int[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class called Cell in a separate java file. Where that class contains an int[]. I see that you also have an isFlagged() method on you Cell class so I put that in as well.

```
public class Cell {
    public int[] values;
    private boolean flag;

    public boolean isFlagged() {
        return flag;
    }

    public setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```